Is there a symbolic computation program that can deal with differential forms, Stokes theorems, the Hodge * operator, etc
I am looking at a messy series of computations of integrals of differential forms on manifolds with boundary, involving repeated application of Stokes' theorem, and also involving the Hodge * operator.
It all rides on whether signs cancel or not.
I was wondering if there is a symbolic computation program that can deal with this sort of thing.
Can Mathematica/Maple/something do this kind of thing?  Any help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks,
Jonathan

You may try https://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/ inside SageMath.
